# Button not filling grid cell

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to build a simple 3x3 grid in Silverlight with a button in each grid cell.  The grid definition is below.  When I add button to the grid they never fill the 130x130 grid cell.  I set the margin and padding to 0 on the buttons as well as setting their horizontal and vertical alignment to Stretch.

```
    <Grid x:Name="Test" ShowGridLines="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="130"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="130"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="130"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="130"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Style x:Key="OperandButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>

 <Button Content="10" Style="{StaticResource OperandButton}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
 <Button Content="3" Style="{StaticResource OperandButton}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
 <Button Content="7" Style="{StaticResource OperandButton}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
```

Comment: You need to give a more complete view of the XAML, such as the button declarations...

Comment: Some button and style examples added

Answer (score 1):

Your code should just work fine. Just try this code as it is.

```
 <Grid x:Name="Test" ShowGridLines="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="OperandButton" TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="130"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="130"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="130"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="130"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>   
        <Button Content="10" Style="{StaticResource OperandButton}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <Button Content="3" Style="{StaticResource OperandButton}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Button Content="7" Style="{StaticResource OperandButton}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />    
        </Grid>
```

Let me know if you still not getting it.

Comment: Here is a screenshot I get with this code.  You can see the gridlines at 130px, but the buttons don't fill the whole thing.

[screenshot](https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=C3DEC8CBC1375998&id=C3DEC8CBC1375998%2122513)

Comment: Cheers I have been searching for the answer for this for a while now moving from WPF Grids where it fills the row/column by default this was annoying but you have saved the day with HorizontalAlignment & HorizontalAlignment

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

When you open your project in Blend. Right click the button, go to edit template, edit current. You'l find that every button has a grid and a container. Make the size of both equal then, you'l see the default border's size same as the buttons size.

The same template can be used for other buttons too.

Now try enveloping the buttons in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the template in blend solved the problem.  The following property was set on the Border:

```
Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"
```

Once this was set to 0, the grid was perfect.  Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's must not specified `VerticalAlignment` Or `HorizontalAlignment`.

```
Margin="-10"
```